# Sort ido results by recentness even when filtered

Tags: ido

I have `ido-use-virtual-buffers` set to `t`, so when I `M-x ido-switch-buffer`, I initially see a list of files with the most recent files at the top.

However, as soon as I type anything to filter the list of matching buffers, the view switches to a different sort order.

Is there a way to retain the sorting by recentness even when the list is filtered in this way?

Comment: Is `ido-buffer-disable-smart-matches` what you're looking for?

Comment: @mutbuerger no: for example when I have three files log, cron showing up on M-x ido-switch-buffer, and another buffer open named orm.py, if I type 'o' I'm hoping to see log and cron still visible and in the same order (because the filtered list is still in order of last used timestamp).  Instead, I might see orm.py show up and log and cron not visible any more (regardless of the value of that variable).